# Mouse freezes after 20 minutes of use

Tags: 12.04, mouse, touchpad, freeze

I use 12.04 and an old HP Probook 4515s. Every time I start the PC, everything works fine but after about 20 minutes, my mouse freezes. Neither the PC nor any program works, just the cursor.

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This used to be a problem and at the time it turned out you need to disable touchpad tracking while typing. A solution was found, but I am unsure whether the same solution will work for you. Worth a try though. Run `synclient TouchpadOff=0`. This solution can be seen at this [forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1852081&page=4).

Comment: that doesn't seem to be a command??

Comment: Synclient should be installed by default. It exists on my installation, using 12.04. Make sure you copy the above command precisely.